# Facebook Graph: PHP: Display Facebook posts/review on website without any login

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

My client has a Facebook page which has his latest posts and shows the reviews people have added.

I want to grab these from Facebook, and output them on his website all styled up nicely with my own markup and styles.

I have had this running in JavaScript with the access token pasted in the JS which is obviously not the way to go, and the token will expire. Now im trying to do the same with PHP. I've read & watched more clips than I care to mention, and I cant get my head around one particular part. Every demonstration i've read or watched requires the website user to login to facebook before this data is returned.

I cant expect ever user who goes on the site to do that. Am I missing something? I just want get the data and display it. No Adding, No Deleting, No Updating. Just display the same information on his website.

Sorry if am asking something stupid here, i'm a novice and for all my efforts I am struggling to understand. I kind of need it in laymans terms so to speak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to go and get a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks. I do understand I need an access token. But to retrieve one, im having to get the user to manually login, then redirect back to the website. That's is what I don't want. I just want the web user to come to the website and the information is just there ready for them to read. Is that possible? I really don't understand?

Comment: You (or another admin of the page) logs in _once_, to request a page access token.

Comment: Ah ok, so once its happened that once, the permission is granted it never has to happen again. Thanks CBroe. I feel a bit of a twit for not realizing that, but i'm very new to all this.